# Prepare data from csv file to use with neural network python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, neural-network

I am trying to get this basic Neural Net working as I am completely new to this.. I can get it to work with hard coded inputs / outputs but cannot seem to get dynamic data from a csv file to work. I have asked this question a few different ways before and get a little closer each time but cannot get pass this error..

The error I am getting -

```
adjustment = dot(training_set_inputs.T, error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output)) ValueError: shapes (2736,3) and (2736,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 2) != 2736 (dim 1)
```

How can I reshape it so the input and output are (2736,3)? I am pretty sure the problem is with output in 'train' as it is reshaping

```
 output = self.predict(training_set_inputs)
```

Here is my data preperation -

```
Model | Trim | Cost | Success
6     | 102  | 1200 | 1
8     | 105  | 1500 | 1
15    | 110  | 3000 | 0


df = pd.read_csv('fulldata.csv')
y = np.array(df[['Success']])
y.reshape(y.size, 1)

df.drop(['Success'],1 , inplace=True)

t_in = df.values.tolist()
```

Here is the network

```
class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self):
        # Seed the random number generator
        random.seed(1)
        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3,1)) - 1

    def __sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 /(1 + exp(-x))

    def __sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1-x)

    def train(self, training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, number_of_training_iterations):
        for iteration in xrange(number_of_training_iterations):
            output = self.predict(training_set_inputs)

            error = training_set_outputs - output

            adjustment = dot(training_set_inputs, error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output))

            self.synaptic_weights += adjustment


    def predict(self, inputs):
        return self.__sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))


if __name__=="__main__":

    #initialize a single neuron neural network
    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

    # training data inputs / outputs
    training_set_inputs = t_in
    training_set_outputs = y 
    # number of iterations 
    neural_network.train(training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, 10000)

    # new input to predict
    my_input = array([6,102,3000])

    print 'New synaptic weights after training'
    print neural_network.synaptic_weights

    print 'Predicting'

    my_prediction =  neural_network.predict(my_input)
    print (my_prediction)
```

whats being outputted from the input(t_in) and output(y) -

```
t_in = [[6.0, 102.0, 0.0], [61.0, 138.0, 12414.0], [224.0, 291.0, 30309.0]]...

y = [[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
```

Comment: Looks like your matrices do not have the proper dimensions for dot product operation. I'm not familiar with the `shapes` notation, but I think you're trying to do [2736, 1] x [2736, 1], which is invalid. Try printing out the two matrices `training_set_inputs.T` and `error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output)` and make sure they have expected shapes.

Comment: Thanks @Posh_Pumpkin, the output from the training_set_inputs is -[[6.0, 102.0, 0.0], [61.0, 138.0, 12414.0], [224.0, 291.0, 30309.0]] And the output for training_set_outputs is [[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]

Comment: I meant the exact matrices that are passed to the `dot()` function at which point the error is thrown. So that would be the `training_set_input.T` and `error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output)` in `NeuralNetwork().train()`. You want the length of the column of the first matrix to equal the number of rows in the second matrix.

Comment: both lengths are 2736 by running print len(training_set_input) and len(error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output)) @Posh_Pumpkin The shapes im getting are (2736x1) and (2736x3)